# Error IllegalStateException al cargar datos almacenados en un cursor

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sqlite

Tengo una función que recorre una base de datos. Al llegar a cierto punto, debe comparar una cadena de texto guardada en la base de datos con otra cadena que recibe por parámetro, pero recibo un error de tipo IllegalStateException al llegar al if que compara dichas cadenas.

Esta es la función que recibe un objeto (el objeto contiene un String y se compara con una cadena de texto obtenida en la base de datos). El error se produce en

"if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("a0").toInt()).equals(p.a0))":

---

```
fun guardarPreguntaFallada(p: Preguntas){
    // Conexión con la base de datos
    val admin = DBPreguntasFalladas(this)
    val db = admin.writableDatabase
    // Cursor
    val cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from falladas", null)

    var repetido = false

    cursor.moveToFirst()

    if (cursor.count == 0){
        // Insertamos los datos del objeto que nos han pasado
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO falladas (pregunta, resp1, resp2, resp3, resp4, correct) VALUES ('"+p.a0+"', '"+p.a00+"', '"+p.b+"', '"+p.c+"', '"+p.d+"', '"+p.e+"')")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tampoco ha guardado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        do{
            try{
                // El error se produce aquí
                if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("a0").toInt()).equals(p.a0)){
                    repetido = true
                }
            }catch (e: IllegalArgumentException){
                Log.e("TAG", "Error")
            }

        }while (cursor.moveToNext())

        // Si no está repetido en la base de datos, no se guarda
        if(!repetido){
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO falladas (pregunta, resp1, resp2, resp3, resp4, correct) VALUES ('"+p.a0+"', '"+p.a00+"', '"+p.b+"', '"+p.c+"', '"+p.d+"', '"+p.e+"')")
            Toast.makeText(this, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    // Cerramos conexiones
    admin.close()
    db.close()
    cursor.close()
}
```

Y este es el error completo:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
at com.example.sqlite.TestActivity.guardarPreguntaFallada(TestActivity.kt:527)
at com.example.sqlite.TestActivity.cargarPregunta$lambda-4(TestActivity.kt:217)
at com.example.sqlite.TestActivity.$r8$lambda$oa_obElNOg5GG_imYFO91H5e88Q(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.sqlite.TestActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda9.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: ¿Cuántas filas con el valor de  a0 te puede devolver tu select?

Comment: Pues concretamente 9. Esas 9 las voy comparando una a una y si coincide se ejecuta una acción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error:

> IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.
> Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data
> from it.

**El problema es que la consulta esta creando un cursor sin información**

El error se produce aquí, donde es incorrecto el uso de `.toInt()`:

```
 if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("a0").toInt()).equals(p.a0)){
```

Primeramente debes obtener el valor del cursor para después realizar la conversión a entero

```
(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("a0")).toInt()
```

y después usar `.equals()` para comparar el valor, por lo tanto debería ser así:

```
if(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("a0")).toInt()).equals(p.a0)){
```

Comment: Perdón, esa consulta sí la he hecho pero se me ha pasado poner la línea en la descripción de la pregunta. Esa consulta la hice al crear el cursor, de la siguiente forma "val cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from falladas", null)"

Comment: Edite la respuesta, revisa como se debe realizar la comparación!, saludos